# jQuery not working on responsive menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is the web page I'm working on: http://example.webweaver.ee/. I'm trying to implement the [MeanMenu](http://www.meanthemes.com/plugins/meanmenu/) plugin for the navigation. I'm doing everything that the small tutorial is telling me: I'm adding the jQuery into my HTML, I'm adding the CSS to the HTML head section, I'm adding the document.ready to the HTML

But the thing is not working...

This is the HTML of my navigation:

```
<nav id="mainNav">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sixteen columns">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Esileht</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sisseastujale</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Erialad</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Vastuvõtt</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Õppetöö</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Õppijale</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Tunniplaan</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">E-õppe keskkond</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Õppekavad</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Õppekorralduseeskiri</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Õpilase meelespea</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Festivalid ja konkursid</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Edasiõppimine</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Koolist</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Uudised</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Üritused</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Meie inimesed</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Meie kollektiivid</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Vilistlased</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Meie saavutused</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Galerii</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Põhikiri ja põhimäärus</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ajalugu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Koostööpartnerid</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--end sixteen columns nav--> 
  </div>
  <!--end container--> 
</nav>
```

And this is the jQuery:

```
<script src="jquery.meanmenu.js"></script> 

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#mainNav .container div').meanmenu();
});
</script>
```

Am I targeting my navigation the wrong way or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your page is trying to pull in http://example.webweaver.ee/jquery.meanmenu.js, but that file does not exist.  You need to update that link.  Also, the css file does not exist.

You should definitely start playing with developer tools like Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools.  They're blessings!